# Hide Product Prices From Google

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I remove the rich snippet of my product information including price and stock level showing on Google Search?

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-product-prices-from-google/

Is the link the best way to remove that?

```php
/**
 * @snippet       SHide Prices @ Google
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli, BusinessBloomer.com
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 4.6
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product_offer', '__return_empty_array' );
```

But, I added the code to my functions.php, rich snippet is still there?
How long do I need to wait for the codes to work usually?
Or, are there other ways to stop Google from showing my product info?

Thanks

Does the below screenshot mean that Google has already re-indexed my website? If the answer is YES, why are the price and stock still there?

[image]

Comment: In general, search engines won't update their indexes right away. This process can take days, weeks, or even months in some cases. You'll need to wait.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thank you for your response. Google Search Console showed that my sitemap has been fetched successfully, and there are hundreds of Discovered URLs, is this the SIGN that Google has reindexed my website? But why are the price and the stock status still there, still showing on the bottom of the search result?

Comment: No, that means that they checked your sitemap file. It doesn't necessarily mean that they have reindexed your site. At least not yet. Also keep in mind what I said before: index updates don't happen right away, you'll need to wait.